# in asp.net how to convert the binary file to a file in a string format and display it in a page

Tags: asp.net

I wish to know how to convert the byte array file to  a file in a string format and display it in a webpage. Can anyone tell me how can i perform this?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Do you mean you want to take a byte array, save it to disk, and present a link to this new file on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of what your actual aim is, a good place to start investigating would be the System.Text.Encoding class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx